# How to get last day of each month in Pandas DataFrame index (using TimeGrouper)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-datetime, datetimeindex

I have a DataFrame with incomplete dates and I only need the date/row of the last day available of each month.
I tried using TimeGrouper and take `.last()` of each group.

```
import pandas as pd
idx = [pd.datetime(2016,2,1),pd.datetime(2017,1,20),pd.datetime(2017,2,1),pd.datetime(2017,2,27)]
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4],index=idx)
df
        0
2016-02-01  1
2017-01-20  2
2017-02-01  3
2017-02-27  4
```

Expecting:

```
df_eom
        0
2016-02-01  1
2017-01-20  2
2017-02-27  4
```

However I got this:

```
df_eom = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1M')).last()
df_eom
              0
2016-02-29  1.0
2016-03-31  NaN
2016-04-30  NaN
2016-05-31  NaN
2016-06-30  NaN
2016-07-31  NaN
2016-08-31  NaN
2016-09-30  NaN
2016-10-31  NaN
2016-11-30  NaN
2016-12-31  NaN
2017-01-31  2.0
2017-02-28  4.0
```

Not only it creates date that weren't in df but also changed the index of first and last row of df. Am I using TimeGrouper wrong?

Comment: `df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).last()` gets close but one loses the day information...

Comment: @Cleb how can I reindex with the last day itself after that?

Answer (score 10):

Here's one way

```
In [795]: df.iloc[df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.to_period('M'))['index'].idxmax()]
Out[795]:
            0
2016-02-01  1
2017-01-20  2
2017-02-27  4
```

Or

```
In [802]: df.loc[df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).apply(lambda x: x.index.max())]
Out[802]:
            0
2016-02-01  1
2017-01-20  2
2017-02-27  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group by the year and month and iterate through your groups to find the last date. Like so:

```
groups = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])
df_eom = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, group in groups:
    df_eom = df_eom.append(group.iloc[-1])
df_eom
            0
2016-02-01  1
2017-01-20  2
2017-02-27  4
```

I don't really like this because of the looping, but given that you really can't have an outrageous number of years and each year will have a maximum of 12 month groups it shouldn't be too awful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this solution is more appropriate in more use cases. The previous instances only work if the the date is exactly a month end. If you deal with financial data for example, the last day of the month may or may not be a calendar month end. This solution accounts for it:

`df[df['as_of_date'].dt.month.shift(-1)!=df['as_of_date'].dt.month].reset_index(drop=True)`